# Can I display a grid or a table inside the div by using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am not sure how to display in the convenient way to the user.
But I have many fields to display in a grid or a table
I have tried to use datatable but I have some image to display so I tried to use grid.

My Grid have display like this
[image: My Grid have display like this]

Can I have a plus sign icon like this
[image: Can I have a plus sign icon like this]

And each time user click on this icon I will dissplay another grid or datatable below the row similar to the Datatable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

basically what i understand from your question is that you want to display sub-records as well with your master records.
i.e:
child elements for a parent element.
well i would like you to use [Devextreme Master Detail View](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/MasterDetailView/jQuery/Light/)

you wont even have to manage any filters, paging. it does all the tings for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try but I use Netcore and Razor view and I am a new bie, I have read your suggestion and feel a bit confuse.Anyway, thanks.

Comment: i have also tried it on aspnet core with razor views. if you want i can share you the code as well. all you have to do is create a parent child relationship between your entities. and you are all set.

Comment: Thank Please share it with me.